# How does Visio 2013 justify the high price tag?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I am starting a process documentation project at work and am searching for a tool to diagram workflows.

I have come across a number of options, some of which are free/open source products, and then there's Microsoft's Visio 2013.

How is the steeper price point of Visio justified when compared to free alternatives? Which "power" features make Visio the favorite choice of business analysts and other professionals?

Comment: What are the other tools you came across ? In my opinion if you are going to use the tool often than go for Visio 2013 Professional. Else search for free alternatives like Lucidchart.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio/microsoft-visio-2013-top-features-create-professional-diagrams-FX103796044.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all as a disclosure I want to mention that I work for [Creately](http://creately.com), a free alternative to Visio. So here are few reasons I've come across for people choosing Visio over us.

1. Others in your organization are using Visio - - So if you're working
   in a team and if others can't open the diagram you've created then
   it   becomes a big issues. Most of the alternatives offers some sore
   of   compatibility with Visio files but it might not be enough for
   your   requirement.
2. Stencils - Microsoft still is the most popular diagramming tool around and there are many Visio specific stencils which is very useful if you're working with a specific product
3. Compatibility with other Microsoft Products
4. Code generation from models - Very few free alternatives offer this and doesn't do a great job of it
5. Reverse engineering - To generate UML models via Visual Studio etc

I'm replying to this as someone working with customer requests, but software engineers, tech leads etc can probably give far more reasons.

Comment: Visio 2013 does not have anymore Reverse Engineering, and I don't remember to have seen the option for number 4. either.